# tfs 2010 - delete WorkItem history

Tags: workitem, tfs-workitem

My Problem is that the Table WorkItemLongTexts is about 17GB!

Is there any way to delete the history of all WorkItems?

Comment: Is your only problem that the table is that huge or is there another problem resulting of the tables size?

Comment: The problem is that the table grows about 2GB each day because we syncronize the TFS WorkItems with another system. The TFS is getting slower every day!

Comment: I guess that your synchronization mechanism is malfunctioning.

Comment: But how can i clean my database?

Comment: That depends on what you want to clean up. If you know what causes this massive table growth you then know what data is added by mistake. Not till then you know what has to be cleaned up.

Comment: Can i delete old Revisions from the Table WorkItemLongTexts? (I need only the newest Revision)

Comment: You "CAN" delete everything. But as I already mentioned: Wihtout knowing what causes the growth I personally would do nothing else than looking for the growth's reason.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
witadmin destroywi /id:<id> /collection:<tfs URL>
```

Comment: This destroys the actual work item rather than the history text associated with it.

Comment: I think this is the only way. You can make a copy of the work item, which does not copy the history, then delete the original.